# Throw nice "logged" error in karmaJS browser launcher

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a launcher plugin for KarmaJS and it's all working nice and all, but when something goes bad (e.g. the browser can't be found)

I want it to display a nice error message via Karma's runner.

At present I'm just doing

```
   throw new Error("my error text");
```

Which displays a nice error message in red on the Karma log but then also shows the stack trace of why it crashed. I'd really like it if I could just have it throw the error that makes the nice text rather than the whole stack trace too.

Is this possible? If so, any ideas how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [use `console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error)

```
console.error("error text");
```

Note however that this will not halt execution like `throw` does, it just logs text to the error channel.